# C++ unmanaged DLL fails to start Excel on IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, excel, winapi, automation, iis-7.5

we have a C++ Win32 DLL that reads data from Excel.

The application uses the following line to create an application:

```
xl.CreateInstance(L"Excel.Application");
```

I want to use this DLL on a .NET Project, so I've built a C++/CLI Wrapper, and reference the wrapper DLL on a C# Web Application.

Win32 (unmanaged) -> C++/CLI (managed) -> C#

The Web Application works fine on the Visual Studio integrated Web Server, however when I deploy to IIS it fails on the above line and returns the error "Invalid pointer".

I thought it could be a permissions problem so I impersonated the Web App but it didn't work. Looks like IIS does not allow open Excel from an unmanaged C++ DLL. I could open from C# but there is a lot of C++ code to read the spreadsheets and I don't want to write it again.

I am running IIS 7.5 and the applicaiton pool allow Win32 Applications.

Could you help me?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Office Interop on the server is NOT supported by MS - see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2

Since Windows Vista MS introduced several security-related measures which prevent a Windows Service (IIS is just a special case of that) from doing "desktop-like" things... which means you would have to circumvent several security measures (impersonation alone won't cut it!) to get it to work (NOT recommended!).

*The Integrated VS web server does NOT simulate the behaviour of IIS regarding permissions etc.*

To deal with Excel in a server-scenario there are several options (free and commercial) out there:

I can recommend [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) and [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp)... didn't try [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) but hear+read lots of good things about it...

Free options (though for the newer xlsx format only!) are for example  [OpenXML 2 from MS](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) and [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Hear, hear +1. I really wish folks would stop trying to do this.